# Trying to create new column based on two columns value and a dictionary with exceptions

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to to take country keys and then populate a country column from it. However, I have a dictionary that contains expectations.

```
excpt_dict = dict(zip(df_cc_ex['VendorAcct'], df_cc_ex['ASO Country'])) #Creates dict of exceptions
df['Country'] = df['CountryKey'].map(country_dict) #Creates new column translating country key into country
df.loc[(df['VendorAccount'] in excpt_dict.keys()), ('Country')] = excpt_dict.values() #Changes new column according to exception

Sample Data
df
VendorAccount, CountryKey
000000       , US        
000001       , MX       
000002       , US       

df after mapping country dict
VendorAccount, CountryKey, Country
000000       , US        , United States
000001       , MX        , Mexico
000002       , US        , United States

Excpt_dict = {000002:'Mexico'}

hopeful solution after using the excpt_dict
df
VendorAccount, CountryKey, Country
000000       , US        , United States
000001       , MX        , Mexico
000002       , US        , Mexico
```

My intention was to first create this new column 'country' and then use the dictionary to find the specific id numbers that were exceptions and then change the country value in accordance with the dictionary. I was hoping for some advice

-- edited to show sample data and hopeful solution

Comment: is it possible to add some sample data and expected output please?

Comment: Sample data and expected output added